# Is there equalizer on the monitor's HD-SDI interface

Tags: video, monitor, hd

Is there usually an equalizer on the monitor's HD-SDI input interface? In fact is it an requirement for HD-SDI monitors? Maybe HD-SDI signal is attenuated too much at the input of monitor, but equalizer inside the monitor will be equalized the cable loss? I don't mention a specific monitor, just wonder that equalizer is such a built-in property for monitors or not.

Thank you.

Comment: When you write 'equalizer', do you really mean 'amplifier'?  Are you saying the signals are so attenuated that the signal cannot be decoded?

Comment: I think "amplifier" term is not enough for "equalizer". Equalizer will adapt the its input signal to a standart-compliant one. It includes amplitude correction, rise/fall time correction and clocking corrections, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically every sdi input has an equaliser as part of the line receiver chip. The expectation is that such things will work over 100m of cable and at sdi rates you need equalization to make that work.

I would be very surprised  to find an sdi monitor without an input equalizer.

There are of course options for some test gear to allow you to inspect the eye pre eq, but if you have that you know it.

Comment: When I scope its eye-diagram, I see that there is no eye. But when I connect it to monitor, video is clear. I guessed monitor has a built-in equalizer inside it. Just I want to be sure.  So in this case, if monitor has already equalizer, is it necessary to insert an external equalizer on the long coaxial cable line ? What is cable length limit for this? i.e:  can I clearly see my video on the monitor where it is transmitted over a 100m coaxial cable without any external equalizer ?

Comment: If the cable (And connectors!) meet spec for whatever version of SDI you are using, it generally just works over 100M. If you want to work much over that or if you have iffy cable or connectors in play then a 'reclocking DA' somewhere about half way along becomes a good idea. There is a reason modern video engineers like the Tek Prism for analysing these issues.

Comment: An external off-the-shelf equalizer could be good. Is there any product suggestion from you for industrial temperatures?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, most SDI receiver chips I've seen have equalizers built in. One of my clients uses the [Semtech GS2961A](https://www.semtech.com/uploads/documents/54385-54385_Doc2.pdf) receiver chip extensively, which contains an "Integrated Adaptive Cable Equalizer".

Comment: Is there a method to understand the whether monitor contains cable equalizer or not?

Comment: Open it up and see which chip the SDI input goes to. Look up the chip on the Internet. Read its datasheet if available.